# Not Able to create IAM in AWS Educate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am trying to create IAM in my AWS Educate but it don't allow me to create.

You need permissions:

> You do not have the permission required to perform this operation. Ask your administrator to add permissions.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Comment: I got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Educate Starter Account are **very limited**:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

One of the limitations is lack of IAM permissions. There is no solution for that. You have to **re-architect your project** not to require the new IAM permissions.